# Display images in javascript condition

Tags: javascript, adblock

What I want is to replace the area where an ad is supposed to be with a picture of my own if the user has adblock enabled.

I have the code to detect weather the user has adblock enabled or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function _enabled() {
    alert('detected');
}
function _disabled() {
    alert('not detected');
}
var _abdDetectedFnc = '_enabled';
var _abdNotDetectedFnc = '_disabled';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://adblockdetector.com/script.php"></script>
```

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: not enough information

Comment: what i want is that if this script gives true(adblock is detected) it should display an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking into querySelector and innerHTML, or look at a tutorial on jQuery

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML

You would do something like this:

```
function _enabled() {
    var adSpace = document.body.querySelector("css selector for target ad space");
    var htmlContent = getAddBlockedContent();
    adSpace.innerHTML = htmlContent;
}

function getAddBlockedContent() {
    return "<img ..../>";
}
```

Comment: So all i do is replace the inside code of what i have with yours? and for the return do i use "" or not.

Comment: From looking at the documentation on http://adblockdetector.com/ it looks like you just need to replace _enabled with what I provided. Just return an image tag or any html content you want in the add space in the getAddBlockedContent() function.

Comment: Just in case you missed it -- you need to put the css selector to you add space instead of "css selector for target ad space". See the linked document in the answer if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

If disabled, insert your custom  tag into the innerHTML of the ad div.  Not sure of the question beyond that....